# How we can to apply filter on TextBox or IText?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, node.js, fabricjs

Just the same, we can apply filters on Fabric Js Image object I am trying to find a way to apply the same filters on text also.

Currently, I am using Fabric JS TextBox as a text element.
I tried the below code but it's not working. I think fabric JS doesn't support it directly to apply a filter on text.

Is there any way we can achieve a filter on the TextBox element?

Also, we should not lose control over text like editing and changing other properties. It should be happening like normal TextBox.

Your output will be highly appreciated.
This is just a feature for text in a video editing application.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.setWidth(900);
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.set({
  backgroundColor: "yellow"
});

function applyFilterToElement(element, filterName) {
  element.filters = [];
  if (filterName === "grayscale") {
    element.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
  } else if (filterName === "brightness") {
    element.filters.push(
      new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({
        brightness: 0.5
      })
    );
  }
  element.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

function createFilterFilter() {
  applyFilterToElement(textElement, "brightness");
}

const textElement = new fabric.IText(
  "QUICK NOTE \n HELLO, \n Filter ON TEXT", {
    fontFamily: "Sans-Serif",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    left: 90,
    top: 200,
    fontSize: 64,
    width: 450,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: "#000000",
    lineHeight: 0.7,
    type: "image",
  }
);

// Text modification
textElement.on("modified", function() {});

canvas.add(textElement);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button onclick="createFilterFilter()">Apply Filter</button>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.